# How to reformat HTML code in JavaScript file in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, html, phpstorm, reformatting

I'm using PhpStorm 2016.2 and developing a web application with VueJS.

In PhpStorm I would like reformat HTML code in my JavaScript file. But when I click `Code | Reformat` only  JavaScript is reformatted.

How to reformat both JavaScript and HTML?

[image: HTML code in a JavaScript file is not reformatted by PhpStorm]

Comment: try Ctrl+A to select all. Then Ctrl+Alt+L to format

Comment: Already tried, it does not work.Thank

Comment: `Alt+Enter` while having caret on HTML part and choose `Edit Fragment` (or similarly named entry) from appeared menu. You can then invoke Reformat in separate split. Once done -- just close it (that split).

Comment: Also tried, it does not work, Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2016.2 doesn't support formatting HTML injected in Typescript/ECMAScript 6.
This feature ([WEB-18307](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18307)) is available since 2017.1, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/using-language-injections.html#d240474e440

Answer (score 9):

I found another solution to my problem with PhpStorm 2016.
Use the Fragment Editor.

1. Place the cursor on your HTML code fragment.
2. Press the ALT + ENTER key and click on "Edit HTML Fragment"
3. Reformat your html code in the fragment editor.
4. Your Javascript file is updated directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Code Style options:

[These are my settings and my mixed HTML/JavaScript gets formatted nicely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uMci.png)

Also, make sure you are using the necessary escape tags on quotations when needed and that closing braces/semicolons are placed properly before running reformat.

Your JavaScript object's "template" uses a ' (single quote) to open what looks like a multi-line string. There appears to be another single quote on line 49 that may be messing up the inspector.

In the situation that your HTML is in a JavaScript string, it will (correctly) not be formatted. I would recommend doing the following:

1. Copy the HTML into a separate .HTML file
2. Reformat the HTML in there
3. Copy the reformatted HTML
4. Go back to your object's string value (template)
5. write: template: ' ' <-- place your insertion point in between the quotations
6. Paste. PHPStorm should automatically escape the quotations for you

Comment: Thanks @Roberto for your settings of HTML code style, he is perfect for me.
But in my use case, PhpStorm 2016 is not able to format a HTML code in Javascript files. It is possible since PhpStorm 2017.
A other solution with PhpStorm 2016 is to use files of type ".vue" that look like of HTML file.

[Single File Components with vueJS](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)

Comment: @Rifton007 I have not used "vue" files before. Thank you for introducing this to me. Happy you found another solution